# Order of request parameters for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, digital-signature

I am working on web service which consumes requests of type  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Here is an example of such a request body:

```
loginId=tester&action=add&requestId=987654321&data=somedata
```

The request is signed (with `SHA1withRSA`) by the client and the signature is sent as a  HTTP header.

The thing is that I always get the parameters in different order, for example:

```
action=add&loginId=tester&requestId=987654321&data=somedata
```

Therefor verifying the signature always fails.

Interesting is that this occurs only if the `Content-Type` is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and if I switch the `Content-Type` to `text/plain` then everything works perfectly.

I've used different types of clients (even monitored the traffic using a TCP monitor) and I am sure that the issue is not caused by the client app.

Here is part of my custom message converter (note that I am directly printing the incoming request to console):

```
@Override
protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException,
        HttpMessageNotReadableException {

    log.debug("> readInternal - message to Object");
    InputStream inputStream = inputMessage.getBody();
    byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    String body = new String(bytes, charset);

    log.debug("Body: {}", body);
}
```

And my Spring MVC configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="converter.NvpHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="charset" value="UTF-8" />
                <property name="nvpConverter" ref="nvpConverter" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>

</bean>
```

I believe that Spring somehow detects that content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and uses some kind of pre-processing. Is my assumption correct? Can this be turned off?

I'm using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your message converter does not work with the native request but with a [`HttpInputMessage`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpInputMessage.html) parameter. That is a Spring class.

The `inputMessage.getBody()` is were your problem arises. By default, a [`ServletServerHttpRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/server/ServletServerHttpRequest.html) (another Spring class) is used which has something like this in its `getBody()` method:

```
public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
    if (isFormSubmittal(this.servletRequest)) {
        return getFormBody(this.servletRequest);
    }
    else {
        return this.servletRequest.getInputStream();
    }
}
```

which delegates to a private implementation like this:

```
private InputStream getFormBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, FORM_CHARSET);

    Map<String, String[]> form = request.getParameterMap();
    for (Iterator<String> nameIterator = form.keySet().iterator(); nameIterator.hasNext();) {
        String name = nameIterator.next();
        List<String> values = Arrays.asList(form.get(name));
        for (Iterator<String> valueIterator = values.iterator(); valueIterator.hasNext();) {
            String value = valueIterator.next();
            writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(name, FORM_CHARSET));
            if (value != null) {
                writer.write('=');
                writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(value, FORM_CHARSET));
                if (valueIterator.hasNext()) {
                    writer.write('&');
                }
            }
        }
        if (nameIterator.hasNext()) {
            writer.append('&');
        }
    }
    writer.flush();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
}
```

This is were your problem happens:

```
...
Map<String, String[]> form = request.getParameterMap();
...
```

You mentioned that you use Tomcat 7 so in this case the `request.getParameterMap()` returns a [`org.apache.catalina.util.ParameterMap`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ParameterMap.html) which is just a `HashMap` which makes no specific guarantees as to its content order. So iterating through the parameters and recomposing the request body is what messes up the original order of your parameters.

Spring is a flexible framework and **you might try to do something about it but you would be fixing the effects, not the cause. And the cause is that your signing method is fragile**.

For example, should these cause different signatures?

```
aaa=1&bbb=2
bbb=2&aaa=1
```

Or these?

```
aaa=Hello+world
aaa=Hello%20world
```

A server normally does not care about the order of the parameters and different ways of encoding values end up as the same decoded value. For this reason, when signing something, you normally **perform a normalization** first. You can borrow some ideas from [URL normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization) or some [available APIs like Twitter's](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/creating-signature).

**You will notice that sorting the parameters before signing is an important step which will remove your current problem.**

Comment: +1. Note that PayPal made the same mistake with their IPN notifications: there is a signature step that assumes a fixed parameter order. OP is not alone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i've solved the issue:

I' ve extended [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html) and override [AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#createHttpInputMessage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.html#createHttpInputMessage%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29)

```
public class MyCustomAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter extends AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected HttpInputMessage createHttpInputMessage(HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws Exception {
        return new ServletServerHttpRequest(servletRequest) {

            @Override
            public InputStream getBody() throws IOException {
                return getServletRequest().getInputStream();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register your custom AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter instead of the original one:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<bean class="webservice.handler.MyCustomAnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean class="converter.NvpHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="charset" value="UTF-8" />
                <property name="nvpConverter" ref="nvpConverter" />
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>

</bean>
```